# Set a ribbon togglebutton programmatically on load

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to set a ribbon togglebutton to true at the start of outlook.  I did not use the designer but used XML to design the ribbon.  Creating an attribute of isChecked in the XML does not seem to be called or used in any way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `toggleButton` element, the callback name is `getPressed`, not isChecked.

Comment: Isn't getPressed only called when the button is clicked?  I am trying to have the default value for the togglebutton be true.  I essentially want the addin to be toggled on at the start of outlook.

Comment: No, onAction is called when the button is clicked: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd910802%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If the post answers your question, please mark it as answer.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question.  The question was, "How to set a toggleButton state as 'pressed' on startup.

Comment: @P.Hinker - it does. The OP mentioned that isChecked callback did not work. The name must be getPressed.